# AWS Amplify with repository in different account - assume role

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-iam, aws-cli, aws-amplify, assume-role

I have gone through the documents and couldn't find a solution for this..
I have two accounts dev and prod. my amplify app exist in dev but code-commit exist prod. Is there any way to connect them?

I have configured assume-role and have also tried using temporary credentials in a different profile and connecting it with:

```
aws amplify create-app --name app-name-in-dev --repository repo-in-prod
aws amplify create-app --name app-name-in-dev --repository repo-in-prod --iam-service-role-arn arn:aws:sts::prod:assumed-role/CrossAccountRepositoryContributorRole/cross-account
```

The problem remains the same. It seems impossible to connect amplify with code-commit until, repository and amplify-app exist in the same account.

Is there anyway to achieve this or is it really not configurable?

references: 
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/IAM/latest/UserGuide/tutorial_cross-account-with-roles.html

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/sts/assume-role.html

https://forums.aws.amazon.com/thread.jspa?threadID=300224

Comment: “The problem remains the same.” What exactly was the problem with the AssumeRole approach? If the Amplify app in your dev account can assume a role that is on your prod account, this should work.

Comment: @JoeyKilpatrick The cross account would let you "create" Amplify app in the prod account for sure, but what i was looking for was that the app resides in the dev (same) account but "selects" repository from the prod account

Answer (score 1):

Incase Anyone comes looking for same: 
After creating a ticket with AWS, I have received back a response that it is not currently possible as Amplify is still a newer service and only allow repository from same account.

> I have tried setting this up at my end and observed the same. I was able to connect to the repositories only in the same account. I did further research on this and could confirm that currently, we cannot integrated with a cross account CodeCommit repository for Amplify applications.